# ExtJs5 -Ext.View.View gets hidden beneath the Ext grid and only reappears after a refresh

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have a page rendered using ExtJs5. It has a tabpanel which consists of an `xtype:Container`,

```
 this.tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        cls: 'tabPanel',
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: 400,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Details',
                items: [
                    this.detailsPanel
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'History',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        items: [
                            this.collectionHistoryTitle,
                            collectionHistoryChart,
                            this.horizontalLineTop,
                            this.collectionHistoryPanelView,

                            this.horizontalLineBottomMargin,
                            this.collectionHistoryGrid,
                            //this.collectionLogPaging,
                        ]
                    },
                    this.collectionHistoryDoNotChangeMessage
                ]
```

Here, the this.collectionHistoryPanelView, is as following,

```
this.collectionHistoryPanelView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
        store: 'collectionHistoryPanelStore',
        tpl: this.collectionHistoryPanelTpl,
        emptyText: 'Please select a row.',
        loadMask: false,
        margin: '0 0 10 0'

    });
```

What happens is that when I click on a grid row(`this.collectionHistoryGrid`) the emptyText('Please select a row') gets replaced by an html template(`this.collectionHistoryPanelTpl`), gets hidden behind the grid and gets displayed correctly after refresh. I have tried a lot of things, but nothing so far has worked.

After Clicking on grid, the Ext view gets hidden:

[image: 2.After Clicking on grid, the Ext view gets hidden]

Works after refresh:

[image: 3.Works after refresh]

Comment: Your example is lacking certain [required properties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Your code gives no possibility to reproduce the problem, since there is no way to see the connection between stores you referenced in the grid and the data view, and how you populate the data view when the a certain record is selected in the grid.

Comment: Have you tried [`doLayout`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-doLayout) on  `collectionHistoryPanelView`?

Comment: I added a listener to the collectionHistoryPanelView, which calls the panel's doLayout, but still it doesnt work- listeners:{
                beforerender:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('panel').doLayout();
                }
            }

Comment: The `beforerender` event is fired once at the rendering of the item, not every time a new record is rendered into it. You can try to call doLayout on the panel from the `refresh` event of the view instead.

Comment: I tried doing that using the refresh event, and placed a breakpoint on the listener, however the event is fired only the first time, during the initial page reload. Its never called again.

Comment: Looks like a rendering problem on vbox layout, including a tpl view. You should either set its height(collectionHistoryPanelView), or wrap the component with another container with `layout:'fit'`. You can also try setting height after clicking grid row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ardabeyazoglu 's comment gave the right path to move on. We changed the Ext view to a container and gave the html template as the itemTpl and everything worked fine.

```
  this.collectionHistoryPanelView = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {

        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        items : [
                 {
                    xtype: 'dataview',
                    itemTpl: this.collectionHistoryPanelTpl,
                    store: 'collectionHistoryPanelStore',
                 }
                ],

    });
```